# Is this a security risk

Tags: php, url, xss

Im pretty new to php, and started to test a few things on my app and noticed this about my URL

When I enter my site by mamp its `http://localhost:8888/project/info.php`

But if I would add `/'%25` to the end of the url string my CSS breaks all togehter

Eg: `http://localhost:8888/project/info.php/'%25`

So is this a security risk? I am not using `$_GET['']` etc to fetch something for a query or so, its just a plain-text info page. But if I add the part /'%25 it breaks the css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it breaks CSS, you have poor HTML then

Comment: why it was tagged with sql, you you said it's plain HTML page?

Comment: Not enough information, what is the url rewriting to. If you are referencing a CSS file, I take it you are doing relative path to current URL causing the break? Check that you can't traverse past document root with http://localhost:8888/project/info.php/../../../ etc.

Comment: Does it also break if you add /banana ? Are you using relative uris for your css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its most likely because of extra slash you are adding. try to replace your `/'%25` with just `/` to confirm.
if so, than you are loading your assets (CSS) relatively to current url.
something like this: `<link href="script">`
try to change it to absolute url, something like this: `<link href="/proper/location/script">`
but im just guessing as you did not provide enough information (link or your code)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not reading GET or POST values then you should not worry. Both XSS and SQL Injection require sending code and SQL statements respectively to the server using input fields on a page.

Comment: Sorry, but this is inaccurate. The uri itself can be a source of xss. So can header values. Next there is DOMbased XSS where the offending input never touches the server.